# Vuejs: where should I place some common js util in a vue-router SPA?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application, vue.js, vue-router

In my Vuejs project, I have some common js functions which would be used through multiple components:

My code structure is as below, which was introduced in http://vuejs.github.io/vuex/en/structure.html:

```
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── components
│   ├── App.vue
│   └── ...
└── vuex
    ├── store.js     # exports the store (with initial state and mutations)
    └── actions.js   # exports all actions
```

`some_component.vue`

```
<template>
// The page content
</template>

<script>
export default {
    attached: function() {
        if(!isLoggedIn) {
            $this.router.go('/signin');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

In this case, I want to make a function `loginRequired` which would be called in several components.

So how should I organize the code？

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my choice

```
├── index.html
└── src
    ├── main.js
    ├── config.js        # Here I define global constants like a base url for vue-resource
    ├── api              # here is all the http calls using Vue.resource
    │   ├── index.js
    │   └── resource.js  # here I define interceptors, for errors log, auth, etc
    ├── components
    │   ├── utils        # Here I define common functions for components
    │   ├── App.vue
    │   └── ...
    └── vuex
        ├── store.js     # exports the store (with initial state and mutations)
        └── actions.js   # exports all actions
```

So what you want, according to my file structure, should be in the `src/components/utils` folder, at least that it uses some http calls, in that case, it would be part of the `src/api` api folder. In this case, the routes are in the `main.js` file, some people prefer to have a dedicated file `routes.js` in the `src` folder, it's up to you

Comment: And should I define utils as a module (namespace in fact) and then `let utils = require('./components/utils.js')` to use it ?

Comment: In fact I use it like a folder, and then make as many files as I need. There are others projects that works like [this](https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap/tree/master/src/utils)

Comment: Finally, take a look at [this project](https://github.com/jackhutu/jackblog-vue/tree/master/src), from here I adapted my file structure

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!